# 301 redirect page to #section of another page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
 Redirect 301 /divisions http://www.website.com/#divisions
```

The following code is redirecting to /#divisions/ rather than /#divisions  (the extra forward slash on the end is preventing the page from scrolling down to #divisions on page load.

Is there a way to modify this htaccess code to stop adding the trailing /   ?

Comment: Are there any other rules in your `.htaccess` file that might be adding a trailing slash?

Answer (score 0):

You can following directive to your `.htaccess` file:

```
# turn directory trailing slash off
DirectorySlash Off
```